# Code just finishes without thoroughly processing

Tags: java, performance, optimization, pass-by-reference

This could be a beginner error as I am new to Java and programming in general. Anyways, I thought it was the placement of System.exit(0) in my code, but when I switched it elsewhere there was an error so I'm sure it's right. All my code does is ask the first JOptionPane.showInputDialog. When I enter yes as a response, my code just finishes processing and does nothing else. What is causing my code to just end instead of processing the dice event?

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
   The Fishing class simulates a game of fishing.
*/

public class Fishing
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to play a round " +
                                                    "of fishing? Enter yes or no?"); 
      while (input == "yes")
      {
         int score = 0;   // Sets player's score to 0
         int points = 0;      // Holds player's points
         final int DIE_SIDES = 6;    // # of sides for the die

         //Create an instance of the Die class
         Die die = new Die(DIE_SIDES);

         //Roll the die once and store value in result
         die.roll();
         int result = die.getValue();

         //Call getScore method and pass points and result
         getScore(points, result);

         //Keeps running total of player's score
         score = score + points;
      }

      System.exit(0);
   }


   /**
      The getScore method will calculate the player's score
      depending on what the player rolled. It will also show
      a message and return the score.
      @return A reference to an integer object containing
              the player's score for one roll.
   */

   public static int getScore(int points, int result)
   {
      if (result == 1)
      {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Waaaaahhhhh, you have caught " +
                                       "a shark. Sharks are dangerous. You " +
                                            "have been awarded zero points.");
         points = 0;
         return points;
      }
      else if (result == 2)
      {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have caught a jellyfish. " +
                                  "This beautiful creature has awarded you " +
                                                               "50 points!!");
         points = 50;
         return points;
      }
      else if (result == 3)
      {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have caught an old boot. " +
                                "Maybe you can sell this old boot after it " +
                                 "dries out. You have been awarded 1 point.");
         points = 1;
         return points;
      }
      else if (result == 4)
      {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have caught an Alaskan salmon. " +
                                "This delicious and popular fish has awarded you " +
                                                                    "75 points!!!");
         points = 75;
         return points;
      }  
      else if (result == 5)
      {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have caught a small fish. You " +
                                                   "have been awarded 20 points!");                                                                                
         points = 20;
         return points;
      }
      else
      {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have caught a treasure chest!! " +
                                  "It is filled with shining pieces of gold, and " +
                                            "you have been awarded 100 points!!!!");
         points = 100;
         return points;
      }
   }
}
```

This is my die class.

```
import java.util.Random;


/**
   The Die class simulates the rolling of a die.
*/

public class Die
{
   private int sides;    //number of sides
   private int value;    //The die's value

   /**
      The constructor performs an initial roll of the die.
      @param numSides The number of sides for this die.
   */

   public Die(int numSides)
   {
     sides = numSides;
     roll();
   }

   /**
      The roll mthod simulates the rolling of the die.
   */

   public void roll()
   {
      //Create a random object.
      Random rand = new Random();

      //Get a random value for the die.
      value = rand.nextInt(sides) + 1;
   }

   /**
      getSides method
      @return The number of sides for this die.
   */

   public int getSides()
   {
      return sides;
   }

   /**
      getValue method
      @return The value of the die.
   */

   public int getValue()
   {
      return value;
   }
}
```

Comment: did it worked with my change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all change as below and try

```
 while (input == "yes")
```

to

```
 while (input.equals("yes"))
```

Comment: That fixed the issue thank you so much. What is the difference between the two? I've had to change it before to this in a different case.

Comment: Refer this link for understanding difference  http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/

Comment: Out of curiosity, I tried adjusting the code to use a do-while loop by defining the input within the loop, but it does not work. Ex. String input = JOption...}while (input.equals("yes"). It says it cannot find symbol even though it's declared.

Answer (score 0):

It's the way that you compare the returned value that should be cause your code not be executed inside the `while` loop. You are comparing with `==` when you should be using he `equals` method.
Additionally you should be playing safe by converting the returned string to a lowercase (or uppercase if you like) like this:

```
while (input.toLowerCase().equals("yes"));
```

Comment: A string is always a string, and no conversion is involved, but == first compares if they are the same object, and they are not, so, if you use the overridden (by default in the String class) equals method it actually compares the content of the String objects.